# Zipf-Mandelbrot distribution citation

Tags: distributions

I am using the Zipf-Mandelbrot distribution in my work according to its definition on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%E2%80%93Mandelbrot_law.
I would like to obtain the citation of the paper or the book that introduce it.

Comment: (-1) All the information you need is in the Wikipedia article you linked to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow up on onestop's response, and save other readers the time of parsing the wiki page, the paper you want is probably the one given in the citations as:

> Zipf, George Kingsley (1932). Selected Studies of the Principle of
>   Relative Frequency in Language. Cambridge, MA: Harvard University
>   Press

though you could also use

> Mandelbrot, Benoît (1965). "Information Theory and Psycholinguistics".
>   In B.B. Wolman and E. Nagel. Scientific psychology. Basic Books

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more accurate. I saw of course these two references on wikipedia but I don't have access to them. Therefore I couldn't double check that the definition given on wikipedia was correct. I'd like to use this distribution for a paper, so I would have liked the confirmation from somebody that this is correct and the best paper to cite.